# how to align equation on the left?

Tags: align

[image]Need help , thx.
after the compiling, it is aligned on the right. but I want to be in the left like in the picture

```
[![\documentclass\[preprint,3p,12pt\]{elsarticle}

\journal{Int. J. Appl. Comput. Math}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage\[ruled\]{algorithm}

%==========================================
\def\ds{\displaystyle}
\def\gr#1{\text{\bf #1}}

\DeclareSymbolFont{msbm}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\R}{\mathalpha}{msbm}{'122}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\N}{\mathalpha}{msbm}{'116}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rand}{rand}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pe}{Pe}

\def\rbf{RBF }

\newcommand{\bfx}{{\bf x}}
\newcommand{\bfv}{{\bf v}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\bfX}{{\bf X}}

\def\RBF{RBF }
\newcommand{\I}{{\mathcal{I}_{i,m}}}
\newcommand{\Ic}{{I_{i+1/2,m}}}
\newcommand{\Iu}{{I_{i,m}}}


\newcommand{\mI}{{I_{i+1/2,m}}}
\newcommand{\hI}{{\widehat{I}_{i,m}}}


\newcommand{\Ip}{{I^+_{i,m}}}
\newcommand{\Imn}{{I^-_{i,m}}}


\parskip1ex plus1ex minus1ex
%==========================================


\begin{document}


\begin{align}
\frac{\delta}{\delta x}\left(a(x,y)\frac{\delta}{\delta x}u(x,y)\right)+\frac{\delta}{\delta y}\left(b(x,y)\frac{\delta}{\delta y}u(x,y)\right)=f(x,y), \quad (x,y)\in\Omega \\
u(x,y)=0,\quad (x,y)\in\delta\Omega \nonumber
\end{align}
%\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified alignment points via `&`. To left-align the two rows, just insert `&` at the start of each line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,12pt]{elsarticle}

\journal{Int. J. Appl. Comput. Math}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%%\usepackage{amstext}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{psfrag}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
%\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}

%%==========================================
%\def\ds{\displaystyle}
%\def\gr#1{\text{\bf #1}}
%
%\DeclareSymbolFont{msbm}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\R}{\mathalpha}{msbm}{'122}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\N}{\mathalpha}{msbm}{'116}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\rand}{rand}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\Pe}{Pe}
%
%\def\rbf{RBF }
%
%\newcommand{\bfx}{{\bf x}}
%\newcommand{\bfv}{{\bf v}}
%\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
%\newcommand{\bfX}{{\bf X}}
%
%\def\RBF{RBF }
%\newcommand{\I}{{\mathcal{I}_{i,m}}}
%\newcommand{\Ic}{{I_{i+1/2,m}}}
%\newcommand{\Iu}{{I_{i,m}}}
%
%
%\newcommand{\mI}{{I_{i+1/2,m}}}
%\newcommand{\hI}{{\widehat{I}_{i,m}}}
%
%
%\newcommand{\Ip}{{I^+_{i,m}}}
%\newcommand{\Imn}{{I^-_{i,m}}}
%
%
%\parskip1ex plus1ex minus1ex


\begin{document}

Without alignment points:
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta}{\delta x}\left(a(x,y)\frac{\delta}{\delta x}u(x,y)\right)+\frac{\delta}{\delta y}\left(b(x,y)\frac{\delta}{\delta y}u(x,y)\right)=f(x,y), \quad (x,y)\in\Omega \\
u(x,y)=0,\quad (x,y)\in\delta\Omega \nonumber
\end{align}

With alignment points at start of each line:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\delta}{\delta x}\Bigl((a(x,y)\frac{\delta}{\delta x}u(x,y)\Bigr)+\frac{\delta}{\delta y}\Bigl((b(x,y)\frac{\delta}{\delta y}u(x,y)\Bigr)=f(x,y), \quad (x,y)\in\Omega \\
&u(x,y)=0,\quad (x,y)\in\delta\Omega \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```